# Greenplum Error-Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop, greenplum, hawq

we have small gpdb cluster. when i am trying to  read external table using `'gphdfs'` Protocol from gpdb master.
 Environment

**Product   Version
Pivotal Greenplum (GPDB)    4.3.8.2
OS  Centos 6.5**

**Getting Error:**

```
prod=# select * from ext_table;                                                                                      ERROR:  external table gphdfs protocol command ended with error. 16/10/05 14:42:51 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable  (seg0 slice1 host.domain.com:40000 pid=25491)
DETAIL:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://path/to/hdfs
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:340)
        at com.
Command: 'gphdfs://path/to/hdfs'
External table tableame, file gphdfs://path/to/hdfs
```

We tried :
Following  link on  Greenplum master machine
https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/219403388-How-to-eliminate-error-message-WARN-util-NativeCodeLoader-Unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-with-gphdfs

**Result of Command**

It did not work after changing the content in "Hadoop-env.sh" as suggested in Link.  Still throwing the same error.Do i need to restart the gpdb for affecting the   changes "Hadoop-env.sh".

Or

Is there alternate way to handle gphdfs protocol error ?

Any help on it would be much appreciated ?

**Attached is DDL for failing External Table**

```
create external table schemaname.exttablename(
"ID" INTEGER,
time timestamp without time zone,
"SalesOrder" char(6),
"NextDetailLine" decimal(6),
"OrderStatus" char(1),

)
location('gphdfs://hadoopmster.com:8020/devgpdb/filename.txt') FORMAT 'text'
```

Comment: Loading Native libs is just a warning, it shouldn't stop things working. The more worrying message in the exception in my view is: `Input path does not exist: hdfs://path/to/hdfs`

Comment: Thanks for  direction. I am going to check for path.

Comment: I just Observed one symptom  : https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202635496-How-to-access-HDFS-data-via-GPDB-external-table-with-gphdfs-protocol when  i checked the  step    able to read data from Hadoop /tmp f directory . but I am creating new dir /dev on hadoop . It is complaining for Input path does not exist: hdfs://path/to/hdfs

Comment: Why it is working for Hadoop /tmp dir  and  not for  Newly created dir on hadoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please provide your external table DDL that was failing .Also please make sure the gpadmin user has permissions to the hdfs path to read and write the data.
Thanks
Pratheesh Nair

Comment: Attached is DDL in question section. Please have a look on it. Thanks

Comment: I already make sure that gpadmin user has permission to the hdfs path to read and write the data.

Comment: Can you see whether you can access hadoop fs -ls hdfs://hadoopmster.com:8020/devgpdb/filename.txt from the master and segment servers .

Comment: Make sure the following

1. hadoop fs -ls / can be run from the master and segment servers
2.hadoop fs -ls hdfs://hadoopmster.com:8020/devgpdb/filename.txt
3.hadoop fs -cat hdfs://hadoopmster.com:8020/devgpdb/filename.txt
3.

Comment: 1. hadoop fs -ls / can be run from the master and segment servers   when i ran  on segmen server it is throwing  error :http://paste.ofcode.org/nBRwFHuMjNnQXXjwgfSRKY

Comment: Yes thats what the issue .You need to make sure gpdb master and segment servers should be able to talk to the hadoop datanodes .HDFS shoule be accessible from all the master and segement servers .Please work with your network admin to have all the needed connections .

https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202635496-How-to-access-HDFS-data-via-GPDB-external-table-with-gphdfs-protocol

Comment: Thanks a ton . This document is good for us. and we have conducted the same document brfore posting question here.Additionally, HDFS data is not secured .can we use knox service for that  Have you go ant Pivotal document for implementing those  knox stuff, please share .(because kerberos is not allowed to me )  can we have  discussion in chat ?

Comment: Were you able to query the hdfs data using gphdfs ? You have to make sure hdfs is accessible from all the master and segment servers and the files should have correct permissions for the gpadmin user.

You can secure your HDFS data using kerberos and configure gphdfs to work with kerberised HDFS .Also ,Knox can be set up in the hadoop side and you have to make sure you have the correct keys and permissions for the hdfs files that gpadmin is trying to access .Please let me know if you have any specific issue or doubt .

Comment: I have started Knox service . want to  secure the  hadoop. But seems like more configuration  needed.  as it is not working after starting the LDAP from AMbari

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this at a customer site. This Pivotal support article provided the answer:
https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/219403388-How-to-eliminate-error-message-WARN-util-NativeCodeLoader-Unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-with-gphdfs

Comment: Did you copy that file to all GPDB nodes? And you don't need to restart GP after making changes to this file.

Comment: not copied  to all nodes and also not restarted GP  only changed the content . but no where mentioned  this to be done in link

Comment: AFter doing steps copy all nodes and restart GP . issue remains same

Comment: Regarding the 'hadoop fs -ls /' command running successfully on the master but not the segment servers, that may be one of the problems. When you issue a SQL command against an external table that accesses HDFS, it is actually the segments that connect to the namenode. The load is from the HDFS file system directly to the segments, bypassing the master.

Comment: This must work from the segment servers: hdfs fs -cat /devgpdb/filename.txt

Comment: Thanks it is working now.  i gave permission   from Hadoop master machien 777. and removed filename.txt to filename in  location clause of ext table . it works for me.